# react-router indexroute doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a routes like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Login} />
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   </Route>
</Router>
```

In the render method of component `App` I have this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Header loggedIn={ this.props.data.loggedIn}/>
     {this.props.children}
  </div>
);
```

When I visit my home `/` the `Header` component is rendered but the `Login` component is not.

The same if I visit `/dashboard`. The property `{this.props.children}` is always null.

What is wrong ?

**EDIT:**
`<Router>` is wrapper with `<Provider>`

```
<Provider store{store}>
  <div>
   {this.renderRoutes()}
  </div>
</Provider>
```

The `App` component right now have no more than the return() showed above:

I have this `propTypes` and `defaultTypes`:

```
App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object
};

App.defaultTypes = {
    children: null
};
```

Maybe this `defaultTypes` set to `null` on `children` is the problem? However, the `Route` i've show before, is correct ?

Comment: After declaring the <Router> component, how are you wrapping it into your app?

Comment: Please provide your all code. Especially the whole code of App component.